# Can't create new page on wordpress site and it bring me to post page. edit.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to create a new page on my WordPress website. I can't understand the reason for this.

Every time I click on save draft, publish or preview, it brings me back to Posts Page: https://­www.example.com/­developer/edit.php. So I can never create a new page: https://­www.example.com/­developer/­edit.php?post_type=pa­ge

Can you have the solution to this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason for the PHP tag on this question? Are you having trouble with posts or just pages. Does the problem persist when you change the theme to one of the default themes?

Comment: Yes...Facing the same problem while changing the theme.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was my sql-database that was over quota.